# How to determine the maximum area of the triangle given by

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

I am trying to find the maximum area of a triangle under some given constraints. I have generated a function to do this. If $x$ and $y$ are Real Numbers such that;
$$x^2+y^2=1,$$
then the area of the triangle is given by the function;
$$f(x,y)=x(1+y).$$

So, when  is the value given by this function maximised (subject to $x^2+y^2=1$)?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: $x^2+y^2$ is incomplete as a condition (constrain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that maximizing $f(x,y)$ is equivalent to maximizing $f(x,y)^2.$ We have;
\begin{align*}
f(x,y)^2
&=\left(x(1+y)\right)^2\\
&=x^2(1+y)^2\\
&=(1-y^2)(1+y)^2\\
&=(1-y^2)(y^2+2y+1)\\
&=-y^4-2y^3+2y+1.
\end{align*}

Let this function be $g(y)=-y^4-2y^3+2y+1.$ We know that the derivative of this function is $-4y^3-6x^2+2,$ which is nonnegative for $y\leq \frac{1}{2},$ and negative for $y>\frac{1}{2}.$

Thus $g(y)$ incresases whenever $y\leq \frac{1}{2},$ and decreases when $y>\frac{1}{2},$ and acheives a maximum value $f(y)=\frac{27}{16}$ when $y=\frac{1}{2}.$

Thus the maximum value of $f(x,y)^2$ is $\frac{27}{16}$ when $y=\frac{1}{2}$ and $x=\sqrt{1-\dfrac{1}{4}}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}.$

So, the maximum value of the original function $f(x,y)$ is; $$\sqrt{\frac{27}{16}}=\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{4}.$$

It is acheived when;
$$\left(x,y\right)=\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right).$$